# Is it possible to change the data pointer in a SEXP?

Tags: r, rcpp

I am sending back many heap allocated double arrays to R and am trying to avoid copies.

I do not want to use Rcpp::wrap as that involves a copy. I also do not have the opportunity to do `Rf_allocVector` and pass the double pointer REAL(a) to my C function.

Since each `SEXP` contains a pointer to the raw data somewhere (double* for REALSXP) and a refcount for the garbage collector, I would ideally wish to do something like this, pretending the R API has a `CHANGE_DATA_PTR` macro:

```
double *my_array = new double[N] // One of many big heap allocated (not with Rs allocator) double arrays I wish to return to R without copies

SEXP my_array_R = PROTECT(Rf_allocVector(REALSXP, 0)) // Initialize an empty R vector

CHANGE_DATA_PTR(my_array_R) = my_array;

UNPROTECT(1)

return my_array_R;
```

Is this possible? (without resorting to the very error prone hack if manually finding were the data pointer can be be obtained from the opaque SEXP pointer and manually overwriting it with `->`.

Comment: Probably not.  What is inside a `SEXP` comes from R's internal memory management, this is in general not interchangeable with what your program may have in heap allocated memory.  See _Writing R Extensions_ for why R extensions should not use plain `malloc()` etc.

Comment: Thank you, I've gone through that entire document (in particular https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Allocating-storage) and I could not see a definite statement that would disallow this, though I get the sense this would be non-standard and a solution would be quite iffy.

Comment: Maybe look at external pointer documentation though, and Rcpp's `XPtr` and the `XPtrUtil` package.  You can manage your own memory and tell R to leave it alone.  But no "plug and play" interchangeability of memory chunks.